# Finding a CDF given a PDF using summations

Tags: probability-distributions

I am in a prob and stats class and we have just begun our discussion on discrete random variables.  I am given a pdf of

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&x/10 &&: x = 1,2,\ldots,4\\
&0 &&: \text{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

I need to find an expression for the cumulative distributive function.  I have done some research and I see that you can do this with derivatives and anti-derivatives.. however, that is not how the examples my professor has done are shown so I am looking for help with that.  I have the following definition:

$$F(x) = \sum_{x_i \le x} f(x_i)$$ where the summation is taken over indices $i$ such that $ x_i \le x$.  I have the list of properties of CDF I am just not sure how to apply it.  For my particular problem I think I need to do

$$F(X) = \sum_{k=1}^x \frac k {10}$$ which would be $$ \frac 1 {10} \sum_{k=1}^x  k$$

Comment: This looks correct. You don't need derivatives for discrete random variables; they are needed for continuous random variables.

Comment: so my summation would $\frac {x(x +1)} {20}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. For discrete random variables, you should sum the lesser values as you have defined.

Derivatives and anti-derivatives are used for continuous random variables. You'll probably cover this topic in your class soon.

Comment: so my summation would $\frac {x(x +1)} {20}$